# Классы C++, не понимаю выполнение строки кода

Tags: c++, классы

Есть следующий код (фрагмент, который предоставил преподаватель):

```
int p::*ip2=&p::pub2;
```

известно, что p - это класс, pub2 переменная в классе. 
Не понимаю значение операции **::** , а также чем отличается при обращении к классу **.** от **->**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649580/using-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ip2` - адрес переменной типа `int`, но не простой, а члена класса `p`.

Ну, а `p::pub2` - это и есть эта переменная, адрес которой помещается в `ip2`.

Операция `::` - разрешение области видимости. Грубо говоря, где эта переменная объявлена. Так, `::p` - имя глобальной переменной `p` - перед `::` ничего нет.

Если есть объект класса `c`, и поле `x`, то к нему обращаются как к `c.x`, так? А если есть *указатель* на объект класса `p`, то как нам получить сам объект? как `*p`. Тогда обращение будет иметь вид `(*p).x` - и, чтоб не мучиться со скобочками и звездочками, это же можно записать как `p->x`.